# Find similar groups of numbers across rows R

Tags: r, algorithm, combinations

I'm trying to find similar patterns of numbers across a dataframe. I have a dataframe with 5 columns and some columns have a random number between 3 and 50. However, for some rows 2 or 3 columns don't have a number.

```
A   B    C   D   E
5   23   6 
9   33   7   8   12
33   7   14  
6   18   23  48 
8   44   33  7  9
```

I want to know what are the recurring numbers, so I'm interested in:

- Row 1 and 4 that have the number 23 and 6,
- Row 2 and 5 that have number 9, 33 and 8,
- Row 2, 3 and 5 that have number 33 and 7.

Basically I'm trying to get the number of different combinations.

I'm a bit stuck about how to do this. I've tried to join the numbers in a list.

```
for (i in 1:dim(knots_all)[1]) {
    knots_all$list_knots <- list(sort(knots_all[i,1:5]))
}
```

I've also tried `intersect` but it doesn't seem very efficient as R also considers the NAs which I want to disregard.

I would like to hear some ideas about the best way to achieve this. I've been thinking about this problem but I'm not able to understand how to get to the answer. My mind is stuck so any idea is much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific/target pattern you want to capture. It seems like you need a process to identify the numbers that appear more often in your dataset and then see in which rows they appear.

I'll modify your example dataset to have number 23 appearing twice in the same row in order to illustrate some useful differences in counts.

```
df = read.table(text = "
A   B    C   D   E
5   23   6   23  NA
9   33   7   8   12
33   7   14  NA  NA
6   18   23  48  NA
8   44   33  7  9 
", header=T)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>%          # add a row flag
  gather(col_name,value,-row_id) %>%         # reshape
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%                  # exclude NAs
  group_by(value) %>%                        # for each number value
  summarise(NumOccurences = n(),                             # count occurences
            rows = paste(sort(row_id), collapse = "_"),      # capture rows
            NumRowOccurences = n_distinct(row_id),           # count occurences in unique rows
            unique_rows = paste(sort(unique(row_id)), collapse = "_")) %>%  # capture unique rows
  arrange(desc(NumOccurences))                               # order by number popularity (occurences)

# # A tibble: 12 x 5
#    value NumOccurences rows  NumRowOccurences unique_rows
#    <int>         <int> <chr>            <int> <chr>      
# 1     7             3 2_3_5                3 2_3_5      
# 2    23             3 1_1_4                2 1_4        
# 3    33             3 2_3_5                3 2_3_5      
# 4     6             2 1_4                  2 1_4        
# 5     8             2 2_5                  2 2_5        
# 6     9             2 2_5                  2 2_5        
# 7     5             1 1                    1 1          
# 8    12             1 2                    1 2          
# 9    14             1 3                    1 3          
# 10   18             1 4                    1 4          
# 11   44             1 5                    1 5          
# 12   48             1 4                    1 4
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a really nice and easy approach! I haven't even thought about transforming the dataframe to long format but that's a great idea. It avoids the use of forloops.

Comment: Thank you! That's a great point! I already took care of that since I want different numbers per row. Your answer seems exactly what I was looking for (but didn't knew).

Comment: I've already updated my answer to take care of this. Also, you can use the `NumOccurences` - `NumRowOccurences` difference to investigate which numbers tend to appear multiple times in same rows.

Comment: However with 300 rows the variable `rows` is a bit difficult to work with. For instance, the number 13 appears 35 times which I can't be sure if 13 appears in combination with the same number or different numbers. I will probably still need to iterate over the `rows` variable to understand all the combinations.

Comment: You can use column `rows` as a variable that you can count and see how many unique numbers have this combination. If you have problems with visualising this variable (large string) you can save the data as a .csv file and investigate.

Comment: The problem that I'm still having if that it won't return the smaller combinations. For instance, the number  11 appears in these rows `19 20_38_55_73_77_97_109_115_117_124_142_170_174_177_201_206_207_208_220_222_246_251_266_276_295_296`. The number 29 for instance may appear only in row 55 and 174. Or perhaps I'm misundertanding something.

Comment: Hmmm. It's should return ALL numbers and the corresponding row combinations. Is it possible that it doesn't PRINT the whole thing? Have you tried to save the process as a new dataframe and then investigate how many rows it has? If any numbers are missing? etc. In your posted example above your example dataset had 12 unique numbers and the process was able to print the whole thing on your screen (12 rows 5 columns).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164737/discussion-between-pavid-and-antoniosk).

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of lists:

```
List = [1[],2[],...,n[]].
```

Loop through your data frame and for your example ad A to List = [1[],2[],.5[A]..,[n]] (at index = 5). And so on for every column.

after this loop through list check if the list (in the list) are filled and have multiple columns.

this should get you started.
good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is an algorithm which can detect numbers presents in two columns.

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(5, 23, 6, NA, NA),
          B = c(9, 33, 7, 8, 12),
          C = c(33, 7, 14, NA, NA),
          D = c(6, 18, 23, 48, NA),
          E = c(8, 44, 33, 7, 9))

L <- as.list(df)


LL <- rep(list(rep(list(NA), length(L))), length(L))

for(i in 1:length(L)){
  for(j in 1:length(L))
    LL[[i]][[j]] <- intersect(L[[i]], L[[j]])
}
```

To see the overlapping numbers in columns 1 and 4:

```
LL[[1]][[4]]
[1] 23  6 NA
```

To see all overapping numbers:

```
unique(unlist(LL))
[1]  5 23  6 NA  9 33  7  8 12 14 18 48 44
```

It could be changed a little bit (by adding a level in the nested loop and if the `for` loop) to see the pesence in 3 different columns etc

Comment: Thank you! That's a good idea using the `intersect` which I was trying to do. I had in mind something similar but it didn't seemed the most efficient way since my original dataframe has 300 rows (forgot to mention that).

Answer (score 0):

One example for dealing with the `NA` would be to temporarily fill them with randomly generated numbers:

```
# data
df <- data.frame(A = c(5,9,33,6,8),
                 B = c(23,33,7,18,44),
                 C = c(6,7,14,23,33),
                 D = c(NA, 8, NA, 48, 7),
                 E = c(NA, 12, NA, NA, 9))

# fill NA with random numbers
set.seed(1)
df2 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), rnorm(1), x))))

> df2
   A  B  C          D          E
1  5 23  6 -0.6264538  0.1836433
2  9 33  7  8.0000000 12.0000000
3 33  7 14 -0.6264538  0.1836433
4  6 18 23 48.0000000  0.1836433
5  8 44 33  7.0000000  9.0000000


# split data by rows
df2 <- split(df2, seq_along(df2))

# compare rows with each other
temp <- lapply(lapply(df2, function(x) lapply(df2, function(y) x %in% y)), function(x) do.call(rbind, x))

# delete self comparisons
output <- lapply(1:5, function(x) temp[[x]] <- temp[[x]][-x,])
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
4 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[2]]
   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

[[3]]
   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
1 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
5  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[4]]
   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[5]]
   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```